# Move one file to multiple directories

Tags: batch-file

I want to move a file from my desktop into these file paths (ending up in the letter folder) using a batch file.

myfolder\subfolder1\env01\subfolder2\subfolder3\Letters

myfolder\subfolder1\env02\subfolder2\subfolder3\Letters

myfolder\subfolder1\env03\subfolder2\subfolder3\Letters

Not sure how to copy files to multiple paths. Need Help.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop is what you might be after: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true

```
for %%d in (env01 env02 env03) do copy desktop.fil myfolder\subfolder1\%%d\subfolder2\subfolder3\Letters
```

For multiple source files, enclose the loop within another loop:

```
for %%c in (file0 file1 file2) do (
    for %%d in (env01 env02 env03) do (
        copy %%c myfolder\subfolder1\%%d\subfolder2\subfolder3\Letters
    )
)
```

Comment: what if I have multiple files to move? say within c:\folder I have 10 files I want moved to the same paths as above?

Comment: I've expanded my response to include the multiple sources scenario.